# Unable to write and open file in android 11

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage, android-11, android-storage

In my application, the button event returns the base64 string for PDF from the server. Then I am writing this base64 to a file. and trying to open it through an external PDF viewer. It works fine on android devices except Android 11. Please see my codes below.

```
 byte[] decodedContent = android.util.Base64.decode(base64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                try {
                    File path = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "PDFData");
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        path.mkdirs();
                    }
                    file = new File(path,  "myPDF.pdf");


                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outputStream.write(decodedContent);
                    outputStream.close();
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                    if (pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No application found to open PDF, please install one.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("FileNotFound", "FileNotFoundException");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("IOException", "IOException");

                } finally {
                    // Make absolutely certain the outputStream is closed
                    try {
                        Log.d("outputStream", "outputStream");

                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Below permissions are already in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "It works fine on android devices except Android 11" -- it should be crashing on all Android devices running Android 7.0 and higher, as your `Uri.fromFile()` should be triggering a `FileUriExposedException`. Switch to using `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: `Then I am writing this base64 to a file. and trying to open it through an external PDF viewer.` That does not make sense as pdf viewers will not handle base64 encoded files.

Comment: @blackapps decoded that base64 to string. Please check that question and comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please give an example for creating a pdf with FileProvider?I tried some examples but something wrong.

Comment: One does only need a file provider to serve/provide a file not to create one. Your file is not created and before that the directory is not created but you are unaware by not checking the return value of mkdirs.

Comment: @blackapps tried the same but getting this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.       used this as path file   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="PDFData" path="PDFData/"/>

</paths>

Comment: It is difficult talking if you do not react on comments.

Comment: @blackapps I tried to reply to your comments and as you mentioned I tried provider only to serve. then I got the above error. That I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: `Then I am writing this base64 to a file. `

Comment: "Could you please give an example for creating a pdf with FileProvider?" -- I do not know how you are defining "created" here, but [this sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider) shows copying a PDF stored as an asset to a file, then viewing it using `FileProvider` and `ACTION_VIEW`. "decoded that base64 to string" -- PDFs are not strings. Modern PDFs often contain binary content.